# HighCharts Date format

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have an application that returns JSON date to me which I display on a Highcharts bar graph. The field for the x-axis is a date and it comes back from the server is JSON format such as :"date":"2016-11-15T00:00:00.000Z"

I want to display the date on the x-axis as just 2016-11-15, or even better, display it in local date format, which in this case would be 2016-11-14 as it is GMT-5 hours.

I've read the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Hello,

Did you manage to fix the GMT-5 hours problem on the x-axis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can parse ISO string date to js date with the Date constructor. And then get timestamp in milisecond - which is a required format for Highcharts.

```
new Date("2016-11-15T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
```

In the format property, you can define how the date should be displayed.

```
 xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    format: '{value:%Y-%m-%d}',
  }
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/akehpzq4/4/

For a local time, see [useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.useUTC) option.

Comment: Works great!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to return format date

```
function ReadDate(dateTM) {
    var date = new Date(parseInt(dateTM.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""), 10));
    if (date.getFullYear() > 1 && date.getFullYear() != 1900) {
        return (date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear());
    } else return ""
}
```

You can read guide at this link [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Yes, that works. But how do I call that function in the highchart? I want all dates on the x axis to use that function. Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Why `date.getFullYear() != 1900`?

Comment: xAxis: {
                    categories: ReadDate(value),
                    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                    title: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },

Comment: @RobG  i catch value Null,you needn't have done this